# Calculating the segregating sites via tskit versus counting

Tags: python

Can you help me understand why I am getting different values when I calculate the segregating sites from tskit api versus manually counting? Thanks!

Example data generation:

```py
import sys, tskit, msprime

ts = msprime.sim_ancestry(samples=3, ploidy=2, sequence_length=10, random_seed=2)
ts = msprime.sim_mutations(ts, rate=0.1, random_seed=2)
```

Example results: I get 5 from API and 6 from manual counting.

```
>>> ts.segregating_sites(span_normalise=False)
5.0
>>> n=0
>>> for tree in ts.trees():
...     for site in tree.sites():
...         for mutation in site.mutations:
...             node = ts.node(mutation.node)
...             pop_id = node.population
...             n+=1
... 
>>> n
6
```